# Strange NullPointerException in onResume

Tags: android

I've been seeing this NullPointerException pop up for my users in my crash trackers. I have not been able to reproduce it myself, and the most mystifying part of it for me is that the exception itself seems to occur in the Android Activity class--at a line, at which, from looking at the Android source, there is no code at all.

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.catherineapp.android/com.catherineapp.android.HomeAct}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2448)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1990)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4477)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.Activity.onResume(Activity.java:1212)
at com.catherineapp.android.CABaseAct.onResume(CABaseAct.java:69)
at com.catherineapp.android.HomeAct.onResume(HomeAct.java:468)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1156)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4775)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2438)   
... 12 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.Activity.onResume(Activity.java:1212)
at com.catherineapp.android.CABaseAct.onResume(CABaseAct.java:69)
at com.catherineapp.android.HomeAct.onResume(HomeAct.java:468)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1156)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4775)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2438)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1990)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4477)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code at line `com.catherineapp.android.CABaseAct.onResume(CABaseAct.java:69)` is simply: 
`super.onResume();`

I'm looking at the Android source code at http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/app/Activity.java?av=f

Here is the `onPause` method of my `HomeAct`:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    this.unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    this.unregisterReceiver(mChallengeReceiver);
}
```

Here's the `onResume` method of my `HomeAct`:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    refreshData();
    if (mMessageReceiver == null)
        mMessageReceiver = new MessageBroadcastReceiver();
    IntentFilter messageFilter = new IntentFilter(CAService.INTERNAL_MESSAGE_STATUS_UPDATE);
    messageFilter.setPriority(0);
    this.registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, messageFilter);

    if (mChallengeReceiver == null)
        mChallengeReceiver = new ChallengeBroadcastReceiver();
    IntentFilter challengeFilter = new IntentFilter(CAService.INTERNAL_CHALLENGE_STATUS_UPDATE);
    challengeFilter.setPriority(0);
    this.registerReceiver(mChallengeReceiver, challengeFilter);

    showFeedbackRequest();

}
```

Here is the `onResume` implementation of `CABaseAct`:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // track each Activity creation as a result event
    String activityName = this.getClass().getName().replace("com.catherineapp.android.", "");
    TrackDao.track(activityName + ".onResume");
}
```

The error occurs in the Activity.onResume() call, which is cascaded to through the `super.onResume()` calls which are the first calls I make in my overridden `onResume()` calls.

Comment: We need your Java code so provide it, please.

Comment: Maybe could you show more of your code ? Did you override the `onPause()` method ?

Comment: @Sajmon Which code do you want? I realize I didn't post much of it; most of it really didn't seem relevant. I'd be happy to provide whatever would be helpful.

Comment: @ZouZou What code would you like me to provide? I'd be happy to include more of it, it just didn't seem relevant. I override onPause in HomeAct but not in CABaseAct.

Comment: Did you set some variables to null in onPause() ? And if yes, are some of this variables used in CABaseAct ?

Comment: please post your code and their nothing wrong with Activity implementation.

Comment: @ZouZou I've added more code. With regards to your question, not really, no. I unregister some receivers, but that's about it. That being said, even if I was setting some variables to null, I don't know how that would cause a NullPointerException in the Android `Activity` base class.

Comment: @minhaz `CABaseAct` and `HomeAct` are around 1600 lines all told. That would probably be overkill to post here.

Comment: @Catherine This NPE are thrown each times ? Or does it appears randomly ?

Comment: @ZouZou Randomly. I personally have not even been able to reproduce them at all.

Comment: @Catherine What's wrote on line HomeAct.java:468 ?

Comment: @ZouZou super.onResume().